# Where to write in latex?

Tags: conversion

I want to write a paper in latex but I don't know which program I should use. I know I can't use word. Sorry if this question is a duplicate but I can't find the answer.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Well, maybe, but you need TeX Live/MacTeX/MikTeX as well.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install TeX Live from [texlive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/), or MikTeX from [miktex](http://miktex.org/). Both have an editor (GUI) to write your text (TeXworks) and call the (La)TeX engine.

You can choose a lot of LaTeX editors. See [editors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides).

Maybe you wish to use online editors like [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com) or [shareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/).